# Invoking OS commands on file from node/express

Tags: node.js, express, multer

Im using Express to upload a file to my back-end, as shown in the code below. Once their, I would like to use node to invoke a shell script that manipulates this file. The uploaded file will be an argument to the shell script (./script.sh file) and I would then like to return stdout for that script. Where I am struggling is figuring out where to put the code to do this. Should it go in the express route function or below it? Can anyone show me how to do this?

```
const multer = require('multer')
const fs = require('fs')
const exec = require('child_process').exec

const upload = multer({
  dest: './upload',
  fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
      if (file.mimetype != 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document') {
          return cb(new Error('Wrong file type'))
      }
      cb(null,true)
  }
}).single('file');

app.post('/upload', upload, function(req, res) {

  console.log(res);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

First a word of warning, it's worth being very careful if you're taking user input and pushing it into a direct process, especially at the bash level. You could end up giving someone a lot of access to your server! I'd generally advise against doing this sort of thing if you can help it. Now that's out of the way, lets talk Node.

If this is a quick process and you want to respond with whether or not the process was successful, then yes place it within the express route handler. If the process is long running, then you probably want to immediately respond, and then kick off a background process. This can be done in two ways, the first is to simply launch the async process and not waiting for it to respond, the second (and more robust way) is to use a message queue. Place a message in the queue, and then have a worker process that consumes from the queue to process the job.

If you want to do it in-line and respond to them with the result of the shell process then you'll do something like this.

```
app.post('/upload', upload, function(req, res) {
    const filePath = upload.path; // This may be the incorrect way to grab the path
    // Run the thing...
    exec("script.sh " + filePath, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        // Handle errors and respond to the client...
        res.sendStatus(200);
    });
});
```

Again, I'd really urge you to consider not doing this as it opens up a potential security hole. Chances are, if you can do it in a shell script you can probably do most of what you need in node, unless you're making system changes (which is also a bad idea for security).